# How to receive data from the smartphone thermometer?

Tags: android, android-sensors

Hi
I'm working on a weather app and I want to show a comparison between the predicted temperature of the zone and the real one measured by the telephone sensors(I've read online that similar applications exist).
However I can't find how to deal whit this, like which sensor should I use and how to access these sensors from the code(like what libraries and what methods) and over all if it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all please start to research by yourself. You get the sensor from the system service. You have to register your class as a listener to receive temperatures from the sensor.

```
private final SensorManager mSensorManager;
private final Sensor mTempSensor;

public onCreate() {
   mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
   mTempSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE);
   mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mTempSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
}

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
}
```

You get your information inside onSensorChange. Check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview#sensor-framework) for more details. Most sensors return 3 values. I think the temperature values should be found in `event.values[0]`.